# stored procedure has too many arguments specified

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sqldataadapter

I've spent all day on this and still feel I'm no nearer solving the problem (whatever it is). I've checked and re-checked the parameter and table mapping settings in the data adapter. plus dataset fields, and code parameters etc etc. The procedure is intended to fill a table that has fields "StatusID" and "StatusType" in dataset "dsStatus".
Is it the declare parameters? does visual studio think i should be supplying values for the declare parameters too? Thanks to anyone who has suggestions or a solution!

the form code...

```
DsStatus1.Clear()
            DsStatus1 = kernel.getStatus(intDepartmentID, intJobID, "Job")
```

the data adapter code...

```
 Public Function getStatus(ByVal intDepartmentID As Integer, ByVal intJobID As Integer, ByVal strStatusCategory As String) As dsStatus
        Dim dsTemp As New dsStatus
        SqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters("@DepartmentID").Value = intDepartmentID
        SqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters("@JobID").Value = intJobID
        SqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters("@StatusCategory").Value = strStatusCategory
        Me.SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dsTemp)
        Return dsTemp
    End Function
```

the stored procedure...

```
USE [microgenDB]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[get_job_status]    Script Date: 08/16/2013 15:20:15 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    /* -------------------- */
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_job_status]
    @JobID INT,
    @DepartmentID INT,
    @StatusCategory VARCHAR(50)

    AS

        BEGIN

            DECLARE @MaxJobTaskStartDate DATETIME
            DECLARE @MaxJobTaskEndDate DATETIME

            --Get the most recent task...

            --Get MaxStartDate where EndDate is null
            SELECT     @MaxJobTaskStartDate = MAX(dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobTaskStartDate)
            FROM         dbo.tbl_JobTask INNER JOIN
                                  dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask ON dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobDepartmentTaskID = dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.JobDepartmentTaskID INNER JOIN
                                  dbo.tbl_Task ON dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.TaskID = dbo.tbl_Task.TaskID INNER JOIN
                                  dbo.tbl_Job ON dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobID = dbo.tbl_Job.JobID INNER JOIN
                                  dbo.tbl_Status ON dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.StatusID = dbo.tbl_Status.StatusID
            WHERE     (dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobID = @JobID) AND (dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobTaskEndDate IS NULL) AND (dbo.tbl_Status.StatusCategory = @StatusCategory)
            GROUP BY dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobID



            --Get MaxEndDate (for jobs where no task has a null end date)
            SELECT     @MaxJobTaskEndDate = MAX(dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobTaskEndDate)
            FROM         dbo.tbl_JobTask INNER JOIN
                              dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask ON dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobDepartmentTaskID = dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.JobDepartmentTaskID INNER JOIN
                              dbo.tbl_Task ON dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.TaskID = dbo.tbl_Task.TaskID INNER JOIN
                              dbo.tbl_Job ON dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobID = dbo.tbl_Job.JobID INNER JOIN
                              dbo.tbl_Status ON dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.StatusID = dbo.tbl_Status.StatusID
            WHERE     (dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobID = @JobID) AND (dbo.tbl_Status.StatusCategory = @StatusCategory)
            GROUP BY dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobID



            --get the max end date coz there's no open tasks
            IF (@MaxJobTaskStartDate IS NULL)
                BEGIN
                        --select the highest order task with the max end date
                    SELECT dbo.tbl_Status.StatusID, dbo.tbl_Status.StatusType
                    FROM         dbo.tbl_Status INNER JOIN
                                          dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask ON dbo.tbl_Status.StatusID = dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.StatusID
                    WHERE     (dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.TaskLookupOrder IN
                                          (SELECT     MAX(tbl_JobDepartmentTask_1.TaskLookupOrder) AS MaxTaskLookupOrder
                                            FROM         dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask AS tbl_JobDepartmentTask_1 INNER JOIN
                                                                  dbo.tbl_JobTask ON tbl_JobDepartmentTask_1.JobDepartmentTaskID = dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobDepartmentTaskID INNER JOIN
                                                                  dbo.tbl_Status ON tbl_JobDepartmentTask_1.StatusID = dbo.tbl_Status.StatusID
                                            WHERE     (dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobID = @JobID) AND (dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobTaskEndDate = @MaxJobTaskEndDate) AND (dbo.tbl_Status.StatusCategory = @StatusCategory))) AND 
                                          (dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID)
                END


            --there is an open task so see if it's start date is later than the closed tasks
            ELSE

                IF @MaxJobTaskStartDate < @MaxJobTaskEndDate
                    BEGIN
                    --use the maxenddate as the task status
                        SELECT dbo.tbl_Status.StatusID, dbo.tbl_Status.StatusType
                        FROM         dbo.tbl_Status INNER JOIN
                                              dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask ON dbo.tbl_Status.StatusID = dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.StatusID
                        WHERE     (dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.TaskLookupOrder IN
                                          (SELECT     MAX(tbl_JobDepartmentTask_1.TaskLookupOrder) AS MaxTaskLookupOrder
                                            FROM         dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask AS tbl_JobDepartmentTask_1 INNER JOIN
                                                                  dbo.tbl_JobTask ON tbl_JobDepartmentTask_1.JobDepartmentTaskID = dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobDepartmentTaskID INNER JOIN
                                                                  dbo.tbl_Status ON tbl_JobDepartmentTask_1.StatusID = dbo.tbl_Status.StatusID
                                            WHERE     (dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobID = @JobID) AND (dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobTaskEndDate = @MaxJobTaskEndDate) AND (dbo.tbl_Status.StatusCategory = @StatusCategory)))AND 
                                          (dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID)
                    END 

                -- use the maxstartdate as the task status
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT dbo.tbl_Status.StatusID, dbo.tbl_Status.StatusType
                        FROM         dbo.tbl_Status INNER JOIN
                                              dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask ON dbo.tbl_Status.StatusID = dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.StatusID
                        WHERE     (dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.TaskLookupOrder IN
                                      (SELECT     MAX(tbl_JobDepartmentTask_1.TaskLookupOrder) AS MaxTaskLookupOrder
                                            FROM         dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask AS tbl_JobDepartmentTask_1 INNER JOIN
                                                      dbo.tbl_JobTask ON tbl_JobDepartmentTask_1.JobDepartmentTaskID = dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobDepartmentTaskID INNER JOIN
                                                      dbo.tbl_Status ON tbl_JobDepartmentTask_1.StatusID = dbo.tbl_Status.StatusID
                                            WHERE     (dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobID = @JobID) AND (dbo.tbl_JobTask.JobTaskStartDate = @MaxJobTaskStartDate) AND (dbo.tbl_Status.StatusCategory = @StatusCategory)))AND 
                                          (dbo.tbl_JobDepartmentTask.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID)
                    END

    END
```

the code that defines SqlDataAdapter1 (copied from designer window in Visual Studio)
it's displaying three tables from the stored procedure in the data mapping window. I tried mapping all three tables from source sp to the one table in the dataset dsStatus, and also creating three separate tables in the dataset and mapping each to corresponding table from stored procedure. Error message remains!

```
  'SqlSelectCommand4
        '
        Me.SqlSelectCommand4.CommandText = "get_job_status"
        Me.SqlSelectCommand4.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Me.SqlSelectCommand4.Connection = Me.SqlConnection1
        Me.SqlSelectCommand4.Parameters.AddRange(New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter() {New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, Nothing), New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@JobID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4), New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@DepartmentID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4), New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@StatusCategory", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)})
        '
        'SqlDataAdapter1
        '
        Me.SqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand = Me.SqlSelectCommand4
        Me.SqlDataAdapter1.TableMappings.AddRange(New System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping() {New System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping("Table1", "get_job_status", New System.Data.Common.DataColumnMapping() {New System.Data.Common.DataColumnMapping("StatusID", "StatusID"), New System.Data.Common.DataColumnMapping("StatusType", "StatusType")}), New System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping("Table2", "get_job_status", New System.Data.Common.DataColumnMapping() {New System.Data.Common.DataColumnMapping("StatusID", "StatusID"), New System.Data.Common.DataColumnMapping("StatusType", "StatusType")}), New System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping("Table", "get_job_status", New System.Data.Common.DataColumnMapping() {New System.Data.Common.DataColumnMapping("StatusID", "StatusID"), New System.Data.Common.DataColumnMapping("StatusType", "StatusType")})})
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is pointing to the exact same copy of the database you think it is? Does your connection string include something like `AttachDbFileName`?

Comment: the application connection string is pointing to the development server. so that's correct. there's no reference to AttachDbFileName as far as I know. Cheers.

Comment: Where is the code that defines `SqlDataAdapter1`? Are you sure that code doesn't also add parameters?

Comment: Ah I've got two data adapters filling the same dataset. That could be the issue. The other data adapter is giving me "unable to retrieve schema from database table" too. I'll take a look at that. Will post if I make any progress!

Comment: no that wasn't it :-(

Comment: If I create a new stored procedure and change the data adapter to point to that new procedure, I get a "procedure not found" message. If I swap back to old stored procedure, it's fine again. What the hell is going on?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so it was because a separate xml file resides on the local machine where the user application runs. Even though the connection string to the server/database was correct in the application, the xml file connection string was pointing to a different server. 2 days + 2 hours because of this. I think you can guess how I feel. Hope this helps someone else!